# Why is there a sound coming from my Windows 10 laptop when some keys are pressed?

Tags: windows-10, audio, keyboard

In my laptop when I press some keys such as <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, etc. I get a funny type of sound. I have added the link for that sound. Why that happens and how to solve it?

EX: FOR CAPSLOCK **https://sndup.net/6597**. I tried this with both installed and wireless keyboard both are same.

Sorry if there is same question on internet.

Please tell what to do and explain why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Start Menu` > `Settings` > `Ease of Access` > `Keyboard` and disable the options under `Toggle Keys`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't work for mine